# (WCF) elementFormDefault="qualified" and attributeFormDefault="qualified" possible

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, datacontract, messagecontract

Situation: I need to build a webservice based on an XSD.

It is possible to make an WCF webservice when the XSD says:

```
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified"
```

OR

```
elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
```

I could not find any clear answer on Stackoverflow or Google. Is one of these possible or both?

If it is possible, Is it combinable with MessageContracts and DataContracts?

based on [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-schema-reference) It looks not possible:

> attributeFormDefault  Ignored.
>
> elementFormDefault    Must be qualified. All elements must be qualified
>   for a schema to be supported by DataContractSerializer. This can be
>   accomplished by either setting xs:schema/@elementFormDefault to
>   "qualified" or by setting xs:element/@form to "qualified" on each
>   individual element declaration.

I also found [this](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/xml-schema-elementformdefault-and-attributeformdefault/) which doesn't like it:

> In general, because of the potential confusion and odd syntax that can arise from a mix of global and local elements in a single document, along with issues that can arise with the default namespace, it is advised to stick with elementFormDefault=”qualified”.  It may be more verbose, but it is also much clearer which namespace/schema owns a given element.  The XML document author can always rely on the “default namespace” if they want to reduce the amount of prefixes.  In addition, attributeFormDefault should be unqualified due to the potential conflict when using a default namespace.

Comment: As a last resort you can always intercept incoming and outgoing messages to apply your custom logic.